# Get file name/path from a file descriptor from a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

In a linux kernel module is there a way to get a file name/path from an `unsigned int fd`?

I'm aware of this answer: [How can I get a filename from a file descriptor inside a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250078/how-can-i-get-a-filename-from-a-file-descriptor-inside-a-kernel-module) but if I understand the code right, I need a `struct files_struct` too.

EDIT:

Please stop voting as duplicated as it isn't. I'm asking for a way to get file's name/path in plain C from a kernel module, not using system tools. 
Said in another way: running readlink on /procself/fd/ is *not* a good answer.

EDIT 2:

Kernel's syscall read `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` takes 3 arguments, one of them being a fd. It's obvious that somehow `read` is able to read from a single file (instead of all files inside an inode). The question is how.

Comment: A file might have multiple paths in the case of hard links - how are you going to know you got the right one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)

Comment: @CarlNorum Maybe this can be circumvented by returning an array of strings.

Comment: I need to get whatever path is currently being used to access that file. So, /path/to/file.txt and /another/path/to/myfile.md both will be fine.

Comment: Without using `/proc/self/fd` all you can get is the inode using `fstat`, but [that's it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529737/is-it-possible-getting-and-setting-file-name-with-struct-stat-descriptor), unless you're going to traverse the whole file system. A path points to an inode, not the other way round.

Comment: @mata there must be some way of doing it. Mac is doing it via fcntl F_GETPATH. Anyways, if there isn't, what is the closest I can get?

Comment: @mata also please see my second edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the answer to the question that you reference is what you need to do.  And yes, a `struct files_struct` from a task is needed, because a file descriptor is only meaningful in the context of a `files_struct` (usually, there is one of these per process).  File descriptors aren't globally unique, just an index within an individual open file table.

If your code is running in process-context (eg. invoked through a syscall) then you can use `current->files` for the current task's `files_struct`.  This is what `read()` does.

Comment: I'm running that from a syscall, so, yes, I can get current->files. That's what I have after a few hours of reading, but I get garbage instead of what I really want. Where's the error? http://pastebin.com/RNrGRVsC

Comment: @alexandernst: You aren't doing correct locking / rcu dereferences, you're ignoring the `qstr->len` and you're only accessing the final element of the path.  Use the helper functions as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8250940/134633.

Comment: Sorry for taking me so long to reply. Your answer from that other question worked indeed, I just wasn't doing the right way. That's how my function looks like: http://pastebin.com/707W1JDR There is one small question that I have. I don't have to kfree what path_from_fd returns, right?

Comment: @alexandernst: You shouldn't call `free_page((unsigned long)tmp);` until you are finished with the `pathname`.  If you want to return a string that you can `kfree()` later, then you can use `kstrdup(pathname, GFP_KERNEL)` before calling `free_page()`, then return the result.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have one more question. I implemented your solution and firstly I tought everything was fine, but then I realised that no matter what process calls this function, I only dev /dev/pts/XXX or pipe:[XXXXXXX], no other paths at all. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: @alexandernst: That is certainly likely when you're looking at file descriptor 0, 1 or 2 (stdin, stdout and stderr respectively), since those are almost always going to be connected to a pseudo-terminal (`/dev/pts/???`) or a pipe, rather than a disk file.  What system call are you calling this function from?

Comment: I just saw your other reply (the kstrdup one). Isn't that pathname = kstrdup(tmp, GFP_KERNEL);?  About the syscall I'm using, it's __NR_read. You can see the actual code here: https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/blob/master/procmon_kmodule/hookfns.c

Comment: @alexandernst: No, `tmp` is a pointer to the page that contains the path, but it doesn't necessarily start at the start of that page.  `pathname` is a pointer within the allocated page, to the start of the path, so it's `pathname` that you want to pass to `kstrdup()` and `tmp` that you pass to `free_page()`.  It is not unexpected that the vast majority of `read()` calls on a live system would be to pseudo-terminals or pipes.

Comment: Ok, so char * finalpath = kstrdup(pathname, GFP_KERNEL); free_page(....tmp...); return finalpath;     And kfree(finalpath) in the function that called get_path_from_fd, right? What about __NR_open? Will that show "real" paths?

Comment: @alexandernst: Yes, that looks right.  By the way, if your `hooked_sys_read()` is going to call `kmalloc()` then it should check for failure before dereferencing the returned value.  In the `sys_open` syscall you'll have access to the path passed from userspace.  Note that not every file descriptor is created by a call to `sys_open` though.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this question, but I was wondering if there is a way to get the real path (inside the FS) to a file from pipe[YYYYY] ?

Comment: @alexandernst: If you're seeing `pipe:[XXXXXX]` then the file descriptor is an anonymous pipe created by the `pipe()` system call - it doesn't *have* a path name.